# How to create safearray of POINT?

Tags: winapi, com, ole-automation

For oleautomation type, there are VT_xxx types:

```
   SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
   rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
   rgsabound[0].cElements = m_cPoints;
   psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, rgsabound);
```

For custom types, there is IRecordInfo:

`SafeArrayCreateEx(VT_RECORD, 1, &rgbounds, pRecInfo);`

But what is the right type for windows' system type such as POINT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POINT` is not an OLE-compatible type. `VT_RECORD` only works for custom types that are defined in a TypeLibrary.  You will have to either:

1. create a TypeLibrary that replicates `POINT` and then retrieve `IRecordInfo` from the TypeLibrary
2. create a safearray of bytes (VT_UI1) instead and then copy the raw `POINT` bytes into it. The receiver will then have to read the bytes according.